# how to stop the double click event in a datagridview from being raised?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I have a **datagridview** in which one of the columns is a checkbox. I handle the **CellContentClick** event to update information everytime the user check or uncheck one of the checkboxes. It works great. My problem is that when I double click a checkbox **CellContentClick** is called and then **CellContentDoubleClick** after that. I want to annul the call for **CellContentDoubleClick**. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could add a flag in the class that the click is being handled, and return in the double click event if that flag is set. but that highly depends on the order the events are sent, and is probably not the best way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that seems like a good option. However, I don't know if when I do a **return** the checkbox will endup marked or not anyways. One thing I did is set the property **ReadOnly** true, after this when you double click the checkbox in the cell is only updated once.

Comment: You could easily use a bool flag to ignore the event when it comes very shortly after the CellContentClick. I'm starting to recall this as a bug... Here is some more info: http://www.aspnet-answers.com/microsoft/NET/33946836/datagridview-cellcontentclick-fires-after-celldoubleclick.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381072/datagridview-cellcontentclick and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/csharpgeneral/thread/e6f3a286-3e93-4170-a895-8c68a616cc37

Answer (score 1):

You can remove event handler from datagrid.

```
     EventHandler eventHandler = new EventHandler(YourdataGridview_CellContentDoubleClick);
     YourdataGridview.CellContentDoubleClick -= eventHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own class which inherits from DataGridView and override the method which would raise the event so that it doesn't get raised.

```
public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override viod OnCellContentDoubleClick(
DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // by having no code here and not 
        // calling base.OnCellContentDoubleClick(e);
        // you prevent the event being raised
    }
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.oncellcontentdoubleclick.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override void OnCellContentDoubleClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCellContentClick(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of annulling for **CellContentDoubleClick** you can wire **CellContentClick** and **CellContentDoubleClick** to a single method.

```
            gridviewTreasures.CellContentClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(gridviewTreasures_CellContentClick);
            gridviewTreasures.CellContentDoubleClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(gridviewTreasures_CellContentClick);
```