# DatagridView cellcontent click Event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Datagrid-cellcontentclick event when I click on row sometime work sometime does not work.

Does anyone has similar issue. I have function to get customer id when I click on row it show me id of row.

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381072/datagridview-cellcontentclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CellClick` instead, `CellContentClick` on activates if you click on the content within the cell.

Extending on that, Cell click activates on more than just the mouse.

`CellMouseClick` Would only register mouse clicks

**And remember, if the question helped, why don't you go ahead and mark it**