# Checkboxes in DataGridView not firing CellValueChanged event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I'm using this code:

```
// Cell value change event.
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if ((bool)dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value == true) MessageBox.Show("true");
    if ((bool)dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value == false) MessageBox.Show("false");

    MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
}
```

It works fine for all columns, except for one column with a checkbox (`DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`)

I need to know the value in the checkbox column (true or false).

What do I need to do for this?

Comment: This is a bad title. Please update it. You can read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: The link below answers your question: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/31c7a954-1a85-4c38-9e9f-e157d33faf0b/how-to-get-the-value-of-checkbox-in-the-datagridview

Comment: Has your question been answered? Or are you still having problems?

Answer (score 23):

Working with `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` can sometimes be a bit tricky since there are some rules that specifically apply only to the `Cells` of this column type. This code should handle the issue that you are experiencing.

The `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event commits the changes immediately when the cell is clicked. You manually raise the `CellValueChanged` event when calling the `CommitEdit` method.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell == null) return;
    if ((bool)dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value == true) MessageBox.Show("true");
    if ((bool)dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value == false) MessageBox.Show("false");
    MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
}

private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

Visit [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcell.aspx) for additional information on working with the `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`.

Answer (score 5):

MSDN says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx) that CellValueChanged won't fire until the cell has lost focus.

Some solutions:

[DataGridView.CellContentClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381072/datagridview-cellcontentclick)

http://codingeverything.blogspot.com/2013/01/firing-datagridview-cellvaluechanged.html

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a slightly different solution.

I use the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event to check if the column is the checkbox column, and if it is I manually fire the CellValueChanged event like so:

```
if (DGV_Charge.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) DGV_Charge_CellValueChanged(null, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(DGV_Charge.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, DGV_Charge.CurrentCell.RowIndex));
```

Answer (score 0):

The best is to extend the grid by creating your own grid, ready with these various "tricks". Believe me, there are a lot of things that need for adjustments in this grid.

Suggested code using

```
Public Class MyGrid
    Inherits Windows.Forms.DataGridView

    Private Sub MyGrid_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                       Handles Me.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
        If Me.IsCurrentCellDirty AndAlso Not Me.CurrentCell Is Nothing Then
           If TypeOf Me.Columns(Me.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Then
              Me.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit) 'imediate commit, not only on focus changed
           End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyGrid_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) 
                       Handles Me.CellValueChanged
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
           Dim Checked As Boolean = False
           If TypeOf Me.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Then
              'avoid erros
              Checked = Me.CellChecked(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex)
           End If
           RaiseEvent Change(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex, Checked)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```