# How to get the last click event on DataGridViewCheckBoxCell

Tags: winforms, datagridview, event-handling, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I'm using a **DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn** inside a DataGridView in a WinForm panel.
When a checkbox is clicked, I need to compute things that might change a Control state outside the DataGridView.

To do so, I have to handle the **CellContentClick** event because I need to compute **only when a checkbox value is actually changed**.

```
Grid.CellContentClick += Grid_CellContentClick

private void Grid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
    dgv.EndEdit();

    // Compute stuff
}
```

However CellContentClick doesn't always fire, while the internal event that does change the DataGridViewCheckboxCell checked state is.
Most importantly, fast successive clicks on a checkbox do not fire CellContentClick, only the first is catched until the user stops clicking.

As a result I end up in an invalid state where the control outside the DataGridView doesn't display as intended because the computation doesn't use the checkboxes final values.
I've tried to [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472205/c-sharp-event-debounce) the event and creating a pseudo-lock using MouseDown and the grid ReadOnly property, with no success.

Is there a way to catch only the last event of a series of clicks? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you call `EndEdit()` in `CellContentClick`, you should evaluate the new value in `CellValueChanged`. -- The fast click on a Cell or Cell content doesn't affect the new Value. You will get the updated value in `CellValueChanged` in any case (when the value is actually updated).

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something. How is the external control getting the cells check/unchecked state? In my small tests… if the user clicks on the same check box cell successively and quickly, then the grids `CellValueChanged` event may not fire, however, if the external control checks the cells checked/unchecked state then it “should” return the actual check state of the cell even if the grids `CellValueChanged` did not fire.

Comment: @JohnG EndEdit() raises the `CellValueChanged` event immediately, before the code in `CellContentClick` completes. `CellValueChange` is raised no matter what, if the Cell's value changes. Here, the OP - apparently - only needs to counteract the effect of a fast click. They *could* just handle `CellValueChanged`, but, if the *effect* needs to be also *seen* immediately, it's sufficient to make the `CellContentClick` handler async and, e.g., `Await Task.Delay(100)` (when the Cell Type is `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`). This nullifies the fast click action.

Comment: @Jimi … in my small tests, I used the `CellContentClick` event to call the grids `EndEdit`. Also, I wired up the grids `CellValueChanged` event. Putting `Debug` statements in each event and in my small tests… when successively and quickly clicking on the same check box cell… I could see the `CellContentClick` event fire… but the `CellValueChange` event did NOT fire. At least I did not see the `Debug` statement when clicking quickly on the same check box cell. However, checking the cells value externally always returned the correct check box value. Am I doing something wrong in my test?

Comment: @JohnG No, that's correct. That's why I suggested to add a small delay to counteract fast clicks. So the `CellValueChanged` handler can run its code. -- Restating, since it's important: the code in `CellContentClick` - after the `EndEdit()` call - is run only after the code in the `CellValueChanged` handler is executed. Assuming the `CellValueChanged` event can be fired (cannot while fast clicking the Cell's content).

Comment: I can only assume that the `EndEdit` line in the `CellContenetClick` event is possibly not getting executed if clicking on the check box quickly. Sorry I did not see your comment before I posted this. Also, setting a delay would work, but IMO this is an awkward way to prevent the user from quickly clicking on the check box.

Comment: @JohnG `EndEdit()` is executed, but the Cell's cached value has no time to update with the new value set in the UI, so the evaluation always returns `false` (no change), the Cell's `Value` is the cached value and the `CellValueChanged` event is not raised (hence *give it some time to update the current Value*).

Comment: @Jimi … that makes sense… thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, I was able to solve my issue with your remarks. See my answer for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Jimi and @JohnG for your insights, it helped me solving this issue.

I could not make it work using `CellValueChanged` and `CellContentClick`, even with async and `await Task.Delay(...)` as it did not fire correctly and triggered inter-thread exceptions in my computation afterwards.
It might just have been me though, but I wasn't very fond of using `Threading` in this context anyway.

I hadn't considered using `CellValueChanged` and noticed that it wouldn't trigger for a `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` when clicked, so I ended up reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17277193/8193643) and the solution is actually quite simple.

```
Grid.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += Grid_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged;
Grid.CellValueChanged += Grid_CellValueChanged;

private void Grid_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Grid.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        Grid.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
private void Grid_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)Grid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

    // Compute stuff
}
```

This code is executed each time a grid checkbox is clicked on, and has a far better logic since it relies on a direct value change.
However it means the computation takes place each time the value is changed.

I believe one could [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472205/c-sharp-event-debounce) the computation in order to improve this solution, fortunately mine isn't too resource expensive so it runs smoothly and I don't need to take it that far.

Comment: The equivalent (*throttling*) method - using either the `CellContentClick` or `CellValueChanged` events to read the current Value of a CheckBoxCell - as described in comments, is: `if (Grid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell && Grid.IsCurrentCellDirty) { await Task.Delay(100); Validate();  var v = cell.Value; }`. Set in `CellContentClick`, you can then read the `[Cell].Value` in both handlers, it should be synchronized.

Comment: @Jimi it is most probably be a beginner issue on my end, but when I try this code I get an `Invalid cross-thread operation exception` in my computation, after `Validate();`. It is triggered because it tries to access the control I need to change the state of. I've tried to put a `lock` on it with no success. Would you have any idea on how to avoid this exception?